# Why does std::abs return signed types

Tags: c++, unsigned, signed, gcc-warning, absolute-value

I'm getting warning for signed vs. unsigned comparison when I'm comparing a `std::abs(int)` against an `unsigned`.  And indeed, `std::abs` returns signed values.  Why was that choice made?  It would have solved the problem of negative values whose absolute value cannot be represented in the signed type.

And then, is there something cleaner (i.e., without cast) than this to avoid warnings?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

// max(1, lhs + rhs). (lhs must be > 0)
unsigned add(unsigned lhs, int rhs)
{
  return
    (0 < rhs || static_cast<unsigned>(-rhs) < lhs
     ? rhs + lhs
     : 1);
}

int main()
{
  assert(add(42, -41) == 1);
  assert(add(42, 0) == 43);
  assert(add(42, 1) == 43);
  assert(add(42, -51) == 1);
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this had much influence on the standard rationale, but it isn't actually guaranteed that `unsigned` can represent every absolute value of `int`. In theory you could have a conforming implementation in which `int` is 33 bits 2's complement, and `unsigned` is 32 bits. On that implementation, neither `int` nor `unsigned` can represent the absolute value of `INT_MIN`. Not sure why you'd want such an implementation, of course, but it's legal and so your proposal doesn't *strictly* solve the problem. The standard would still permit implementations where you can't do `abs(INT_MIN)`!

Comment: And in practice, the fact that there's one value of `int` on which you can't do `abs` isn't really any more hassle than the fact that there's one value of `int` on which you can't do `--`. And likewise a value on which you can't do `++`. The authors of C and C++ don't hate undefined overflow behavior enough to remove it.

Comment: @SteveJessop How's that possible given §3.9.1-3 (same amount of storage and same object representation for `unsigned int` and `int`)?

Comment: @ChristianRau: different numbers of padding bits. Whether a bit participates in the value or not isn't part of the *object representation*, it's part of the *value representation*. It's pretty academic, but C and C++ are determined to allow for funny architectures. I say funny: verging on hilarious. 32 and 31 would be more plausible than 33 and 32, though, with an 8 bit byte. I'm not sure, but I think there may have been machines where the sign bit was unused in unsigned types (although `unsigned char` would have to use it). Whether they had standard-conforming C++ compilers is another matter.

Comment: Didn't Cray have an `int` type like that? IIRC it used the `float` layout, but with exponent bits set to zero. And for `unsigned int`, probably the sign bit was set to zero as well.

Comment: Of course, this whole mess would have been prevented if we had defined `abs(x)` as the closest representable value. That would have implied `abs(INT_MIN)==INT_MAX` on those funny representations with an unused sign bit.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610947/why-does-stdlib-hs-abs-family-of-functions-return-a-signed-value

Comment: Limiting the possible values of the type (e.g. with unsigned) does not really prevent operations like subtracting a larger value from a smaller one. It is your job to ensure the preconditions of code and do error handling. If you want to automate it more, create your own arithmetic type class and overload the usual operations. Then you can saturate, ignore errors, throw exceptions, whatever you like. For the standard types it is recommended to (nearly) always use signed types for arithmetic computations, even if the value always is positive. And to use unsigned types for bit operations.

Comment: @Sebastian: this is very true... indeed `unsigned` is very different (in semantic) from "non-negative" and shouldn't be used in math computations (unless you want modulo integers) but this is a dangerous thing to say publicly.
Some `unsigned`-obsessed coders will tell you that the name is right, that semantic doesn't matter, that `3u-4u` is weird because of overflow (wrong) and even that Stroustrup himself is wrong when saying that using an `unsigned` to avoid negatives is never a good choice.
I even got banned from a discord server for explaining why `unsigned` is not  "non-negative".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is that this is done so that the return type of `abs` is the same as its input type. This is exactly what you want, most of the time.

Mostly, when calling abs, you're dealing with an equation where all elements are of the same type (or you'd get warnings) and you want to use the magnitude of some variable in that equation. That doesn't mean you want to change the type of one of the variables in your equation. That would give the kind of issues/warnings you're mentioning.

So, in short, it is more common and more natural to want the same input and output type when asking for the absolute value of a signed variable. The magnitude of value isn't commonly used as an index.

Comment: +1 Absolutely. In the end it's a mathematical function and not supposed to mess my types around. You don't want `std::abs(1.0)` to return an `unsigned double` either. In the same way `std::floor` doesn't return an `int` (ok, this one might also be concerned about representable ranges in addition to mere conceptual type conservation).

Comment: @ChristianRau: I don't know what an `unsigned double` is, but I certainly don't want one *ever* ;-) And some people would say much the same about unsigned integer types.

Comment: @ChristianRau Exactly my point! Also, I agree with @SteveJessop that an `unsigned double` sounds very unmotivated and I certainly don't miss it in the standard.

Comment: @SteveJessop & Argentlien Well, you never know when you need that extra bit of precision in a context where numbers cannot be negative. But Ok, this would probably make the actual computing machinery unneccessarily more complex, I guess (since a floating point type not backed by an IEEE standardization and a hardware implementation is pretty useless anyway). But I'm wandering anyway ;)

Comment: @SteveJessop: "And some people would say much the same about unsigned integer types".  Well, I do know people who work in Java and rage against it about every day for its lack of unsigned integers.

Answer (score 4):

In c++11 you could write your own to make to cast automatic:

```
#include <utility>

template< typename T >
typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type  abs( T x )
{
    //We need to cast before negating x to avoid the overflow.
    return x < 0? -static_cast<std::make_unsigned<T>::type>(x) : x;
}
```

I tried it with -Wall options, got no warnings.

Comment: Btw this code still has UB when passed `INT_MIN`, it doesn't "solve the problem of negative values whose absolute value cannot be represented". But it does save typing out the `static_cast` every time you use it.

Comment: I thought so too, but then I tried:

 int x = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
 unsigned y = my_abs(x); 
 
 cout << x << endl;
 cout << y << endl;

Comment: The things is that if you have a N bits signed integer that is equal -2^(N-1), you cannot represent it's absolute value with the same format (i.e. N bits signed integer) since the greatest number that can be represented is 2^(N-1)-1.  But std::make_unsigned<T>::type  gives a 2^N unsigned which have a maximum of 2^N which is greater than any signed value with the same amount of bits.

Comment: The problem is that `-x` has type `T`, and overflows with the 2's complement min value before you have a chance to convert to the unsigned type. On your implementation, when you tested it, that overflow was harmless, but it isn't guaranteed to be harmless. A safe alternative would be `return (x < 0) ? static_cast<std::make_unsigned<T>>(-(x+1))+1 : x;`, and you can hope that maybe the optimizer will sort it out.

Comment: I see,  -static_cast<std::make_unsigned<T>>(x) would be sufficient no? Instead of forcing it to overflow. ?

Comment: Yes, I think that works. You could even make it a bit shorter with `-static_cast<decltype(my_abs(x))>(x)` rather than repeating the return type definition :-)

Comment: I'd recommend a different name like `uabs` for a version different from `std::abs`.  There's a whole Q&A about how to write this. [Is there a safe way to get the unsigned absolute value of a signed integer, without triggering overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17313579)  (I just edited it to add a templated version before spotting this answer).

Comment: A better test would be something that *does* complain with `INT_MIN` or `LONG_MIN`.  UB doesn't mean required to fail; it's expected that it will happen to work on normal machines, especially if you don't enable optimization.  So what you want is to compile a test caller with `gcc -O3 -fsanitize=undefined`, and make sure it *does* generate code to `call __ubsan_handle_negate_overflow` if you pass `LONG_MIN` to `std::abs`, but not with your version.  Like https://godbolt.org/z/W5osanPMM, also in my edit to the answer linked in my last comment.  Anyway yes, this version looks safe.

Answer (score 0):

That is no choice, that is definition. abs is implemented via a template, which returns the type in which the original value was stored. The result will always be valid, as the absolute value of an signed integer will always fit in its original data type. An explicit cast to your target data type should be enough to get rid of any warnings...

Comment: "the absolute value of an signed integer will always fit in his original data type" -- that's not true. On almost all implementations, the absolute value of `INT_MIN` doesn't fit in `int`, and `abs(INT_MIN)` causes overflow.

Comment: `abs is implemented via a template`. The [abs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) I know is not a template.

Comment: These are the variants of abs that exist according to the standard: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs
The only ones of these that are templated are those that take template types as input. (valarray and complex).

Comment: I don't understand what "That is no choice, that is definition... implemented via a template".  It seems that you claim that the interface of the function was dictated by its implementation (which is based on overloading as already reported).  Of course it _must_ be the opposite.

Comment: It is a template for complex values: template<class T> T abs (const complex<T>& x); but I confused that with the standard implementation. You are both right.