# Is there a safe way to get the unsigned absolute value of a signed integer, without triggering overflow?

Tags: c++, integer, integer-overflow, absolute-value, signed-overflow

Consider a typical absolute value function (where for the sake of argument the integral type of maximum size is long):

```
unsigned long abs(long input);
```

A naive implementation of this might look something like:

```
unsigned long abs(long input)
{
    if (input >= 0)
    {
        // input is positive
        // We know this is safe, because the maximum positive signed
        // integer is always less than the maximum positive unsigned one
        return static_cast<unsigned long>(input);
    }
    else
    {
        return static_cast<unsigned long>(-input); // ut oh...
    }
}
```

This code triggers undefined behavior, because the negation of `input` may overflow, and triggering signed integer overflow is undefined behavior. For instance, on 2s complement machines, the absolute value of `std::numeric_limits<long>::min()` will be 1 greater than `std::numeric_limits<long>::max()`.

What can a library author do to work around this problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One can cast to the unsigned variant first to avoid any undefined behavior:

```
unsigned long uabs(long input)
{
    if (input >= 0)
    {
        // input is positive
        return static_cast<unsigned long>(input);
    }
    else
    {
        return -static_cast<unsigned long>(input); // read on...
    }
}
```

In the above code, we invoke two well defined operations. Converting the signed integer to the unsigned one is well defined by N3485 4.7 [conv.integral]/2:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). — end note ]

This basically says that when making the specific conversion of going from signed to unsigned, one can assume unsigned-style wraparound.

The negation of the unsigned integer is well defined by 5.3.1 [expr.unary.op]/8:

> The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from 2^n , where n is the number of bits in the promoted operand.

These two requirements effectively force implementations to operate like a 2s complement machine would, even if the underlying machine is a 1s complement or signed magnitude machine.

---

A generalized C++11 version that returns the unsigned version of an integral type:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
constexpr
typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type uabs(T x)
{
    typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type ux = x;
    return (x<0) ? -ux : ux;   // compare signed x, negate unsigned x
}
```

This compiles [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:20,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:20),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Climits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconstexpr%0Atypename+std::make_unsigned%3CT%3E::type+uabs(T+x)%0A%7B%0A++++typename+std::make_unsigned%3CT%3E::type+ux+%3D+x%3B%0A++++return+(x%3C0)+%3F+-ux+:+ux%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aunsigned+long+test()%7B%0A++++return+uabs(std::numeric_limits%3Clong%3E::min())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0Aunsigned+long+test_ub()%7B%0A++++//+UB+sanitizer+will+trigger+if+this+function+were+called,+unlike+test()%0A++++return+std::abs(std::numeric_limits%3Clong%3E::min())%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:46.438942381170705,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-fsanitize%3Dundefined%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:53.56105761882928,l:%274%27,m:61.40495867768595,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:38.59504132231405,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:53.56105761882928,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), with a test case showing that `gcc -O3 -fsanitize=undefined` finds no UB in `uabs(std::numeric_limits<long>::min());` after constant-propagation, but does in `std::abs()`.

Further template stuff should be possible to make a version that would return the unsigned version of integral types, but return `T` for floating-point types, if you want a general-purpose replacement for `std::abs`.

Comment: Nice answer, albeit to your own question, but +1.

Comment: You can write this compactly as `return x<0 ? 0UL - x : x;`.  That uses implicit conversion to the unsigned type in `0UL - x`, vs. your way explicitly documenting when the conversion happens.  The explicit way is probably good for clarity, although you might do `unsigned long ux = static_cast<unsigned long>(x);` `return x<0 : -ux : ux;` to still write it as a ternary, hinting compilers to do it branchlessly.  And to avoid repeating the conversion, especially if you want to template it to deduce the unsigned version of the input type so the cast is even longer.

Comment: A name like `uabs` or `absu` would be better than `abs`.  I know `abs` is different from `std::abs` in C++, but for human readers it's worth the reminder that this is a function that returns unsigned, and is well-defined for every input, unlike the inconvenient `std::abs`, and C's `abs` from stdlib.h.  (People who regularly work with C as well as C++ will tend to think of that.)

Answer (score 1):

Just add one if negative.

```
unsigned long absolute_value(long x) {
  if (x >= 0) return (unsigned long)x;
  x = -(x+1);
  return (unsigned long)x + 1;
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: compilers are smart enough to untangle this back to an efficient `abs()` idiom for whatever target machine. e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/34h3v8KrP shows GCC for RISC-V compiling it to a branchless bithack, with `-O2`.  And clang for x86 using `neg`/`cmov`.  But I still wouldn't write the source this way; I'd much rather use unsigned operations to avoid UB, without extra operations that I want the compiler to remove. Also in terms of readability and easy verification of correctness just from looking at it, this takes a small amount of effort vs. near zero.

Comment: It's interesting to observe why my answer works: in two's complement negation means bitwise not, plus 1. So `(-(x+1) + 1)` reduces to `(~x + 1)` reduces to `-x`. No compiler heroics required! But I certainly agree with your point regarding readibility.